Android. How to start a local voice interaction triggered directly by pressing on a notification while being in lockscreen on API 31+ devices
Android. How to start a local voice interaction triggered directly by pressing on a button in a notification while being in lockscreen on API 31+ devices. App needs to be set as the default digital assistant.
On API 30 and below PendingIntent.getBroadcast can be used together with an activity intent and then call Activity.startLocalVoiceInteraction(bundle), but that does not work on API 31 and later because of the notification trampoline prohibition.
If using PendingIntent.getActivity together with Activity.startLocalVoiceInteraction(bundle) then it kind of works, but since it is using "getActivity" the notification field will be collapsed, and if user is in lockscreen, then a click on the notification will force the user to unlock the device so that the activity can start, thus not directly starting the voice interaction.
If instead of PendingIntent.getActivity using PendingIntent.getBroadcast there will be no activity, so not possible to use the Activity.startLocalVoiceInteraction(bundle) method to start the voice interaction.
There is also a method Activity.showAssist(bundle) that does the same as Activity.startLocalVoiceInteraction(bundle), but it does not work with PendingIntent.getActivity because the activity is not the focused one, and also does not work with PendingIntent.getBroadcast.
I have tried using PendingIntent.getBroadcast while having an activity running in the background, and using the Activity.startLocalVoiceInteraction(bundle) through an activity retrieved from a WeakReference, but it does not work because it will complain that the activity is not the foreground activity. Maybe TaskStackBuilder could fix the not foreground activity problem somehow? Maybe aquiring the "Show on top of other activities" permission would make it work, but then user has to accept that.
Is there maybe some intent that can be sent to start the voice interaction? Some kind of intent using the action android.intent.action.ASSIST maybe. In that case a PendingIntent.getBroadcast could be used and no need for an activity.
